# Azure Mobile services : using shared libraries in Custom API

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Azure Mobile services (node.js backend) : I remember vaguely sometime back I had read somewhere that the shared libraries cannot be used in Custom API, however I don't remember where exactly I read that. Tried googling, searching here in SO, but didn't find anything. 
Now that I started coding my Custom API, I need to know this for sure, whether what I remember vaguely is really true or not; if someone has any idea about this, I'll much appreciate if you can confirm.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create shared scripts and use them from your mobile service custom API scripts.

See this link for enabling source control and getting a local copy so you can create and push your scripts: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-store-scripts-source-control/#use-npm

Then take a look at this link for more on using some of the "native" node modules or helper functions: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/#shared-code